# Using broadcast in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Anybody knows how to use sendBroadcast and BroadcastReceiver for different application? Actually I have already used sendBroadcast and BroadcastReceiver but in the same project. Now I want to try to send to another application. Anybody knows?

In my previous project I broadcast like this in mainActivity:

```
Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent("SendMessage");
broadCastIntent.putExtra("NAME", gameName);
broadCastIntent.putExtra("JOB",jobStatus);
broadCastIntent.putExtra("STATUS",gameStatus);
sendBroadcast( broadCastIntent );
Log.d("Broadcast sent", gameName );
```

Also I add method to check the intent:

```
protected void onResume()
    {

        if (receiver == null)
        {
            receiver = new myBroadcastReceiver(); --> Here I call the receiver from another package
        }
        registerReceiver(reciever, new IntentFilter("SendMessage"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(reciever);
    }
```

And in another package but in one project , I have created myBroadcastReceiver class for Receive the intent:

```
public class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String status = intent.getStringExtra("STATUS");
        String job = intent.getStringExtra("JOB");
        String media = intent.getStringExtra("MEDIA");
        GameWorldExtension.job = job;
        GameWorldExtension.media = media;
        GameWorldExtension.status = status;
        Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + GameWorldExtension.status);
    }
```

}

I have try and it works fine. Right now I want to try to send into another application. I have tried many ways, but it didn't successful. Anybody knows how to send in right order?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this post could help you. There is an example of BroadcastReceiver that listening "onWifiChange" event.
[How to use Broadcast Receiver in different Applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749893/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver-in-different-applications-in-android)

------- added

On Sender side:

1) Sender class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent("pacman.intent.action.BROADCAST");
    intent.putExtra("message","Wake up.");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

On Receiver side:

1) Receiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Message at Pacman received!");
    }
}
```

2) Receiver manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.ex.myapplication2.MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="pacman.intent.action.BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hi someGuy, thank you for your answer. As I see from example "onWifiChange" I couldn't find how the intent is broadcasted. I would like to know both ways, how to send and received it.