# How to transfer data between two android application

Tags: android, package, transfer

I want to transfer data between two android application. 
Is it possible? 
The two applications were written by myself. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You gotta be using **Content Providers**

Here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

And **Broadcast Recievers**

Here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

This should help: [How to use Broadcast Receiver in different Applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749893/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver-in-different-applications-in-android)